# Cannot find element by class in BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying use the search engine of AllMusic to find songs. As an example, I look for songs whose title matches exactly "Hola" using the url

[https://www.allmusic.com/search/songs/"hola"](https://www.allmusic.com/search/songs/%22hola%22)

So I do `results = requests.get(r'https://www.allmusic.com/search/songs/"hola"')` followed by `soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, 'html.parser')`. One can see that search results are listed with the class `song`, nevertheless when I use `soup.find_all("li", class_="song")` and empty list is returned.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a valid user agent to the request header to get back the page source successfully.

Code:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
results = requests.get(r'https://www.allmusic.com/search/songs/"hola"',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, 'html.parser')
names = soup.find_all("li", class_="song")
```